# Camera connected, but nothing happened, openCV-IP Webcam Android

Tags: c++, opencv, ip, ip-camera, webcam-capture

Here's the deal, I'm trying to interface my S3 as webcam, using IP WebCam app for android, then making a IP webcam within the software, usually the address is http://192.168.1.XX:8080/greet.html maybe the last two digits changes , the webpage give me options and info like this:

```
"Here is the list of IP Webcam service URLs:  
http://192.168.1.XX:8080/video is the MJPEG URL."
```

The code I'm using is simply like this:

```
include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp
include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp
using namespace cv;
int main(){
    VideoCapture cap("http://192.168.1.XX:8080/video.mjpg"); // connect to an ip-cam ( might need some additional dummy param like: '?type=mjpeg' at the end
    while(cap.isOpened()){
        Mat frame;
        if (!cap.read(frame))
            break;
        imshow("lalala",frame);
        int k = waitKey(10);
        if ( k==27 )
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So the IP WebCam app recognice a connection but there's no image whatsoever... and then it says:

```
warning: Error opening file <../../modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_imp
Cannot open the web cam

Process returned -1 <0xFFFFFFF> execution time: 37.259 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I am using:
Windows 7 Professional
Open CV 2.4.4
Codeblocks 13.12
USB 2.0 webcam 640x480 at 30fps, 50 Hz and all standard.

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect another video streaming android application.
I use Smart WebCam.
open it with

```
cap.open("http://192.168.1.13:8080/?x.mjpg);
```